# Having trouble visualizing what a differentiable function with discontinuous derivative looks like

Tags: calculus

So I know that it's possible for a differentiable function to have a discontinuous derivative.  For example, https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_differentiable_function_need_not_be_continuous

But I don't know how to visualize it in general cases.

Just say for example a differentiable function f where f '(x) = 0 for all x $\neq$ 0, but f '(x) = 1 for x = 0.  What does f look like?  I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: derivatives satisfy the intermediate value property so your example is not a derivative

Comment: Take $f(x)=|x|$, then $f'(x)=1$ for $x>0$ and $f'(x)=-1$ for $x<0$ (unless you want $f$ to be differentiable at $x=0$).

Comment: @Tuvasbien : Of course, OP states that $f$ is required to be differentiable

Answer (score 4):

While indeed differentiable functions need not to have continuous derivatives

(see $f(x)=x^2\sin 1/x, x \ne 0, f(0)=0$),

the derivatives satisfy the intermediate value property by [Darboux Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29), so your example is not the derivative of an everywhere differentiable function.

Comment: Ahh, I was not aware of this theorem... thank you!

Comment: happy to be of help - the structure of (non-continuous) derivatives is quite tricky and one of those "deep" real analysis problems that give rise to weird examples/counterexamples  (they have dense points of continuity for example so not all Darboux functions can be derivatives either as there some of those everywhere discontinuous)

Comment: ok so just so I'm clear on what's going on - the derivative I gave as an example in my original post - is that just not a possible derivative for any kind of function (differentiable or not)?  Even though f '(x) exists for all x?

Comment: What does it mean derivative of a function that is not differentiable?

Comment: Hmm, good point.  So I guess the bottom line is that it isn't enough for a derivative f '(x) to simply be defined at every point to say that f is differentiable.  Is that right?

Comment: yes - $f'$ needs to be a very special kind of function if it is not continuous; in other words if you give a function $g$ that is not continuos like in your example, it is highly unlikely that you will find an $f$ for which $f'=g$ everywhere - obviously you can find $f$ with $f'=g$ outside of $0$ but that is trivial since $g$ is continuous there; no value you give $g$ at $0$ except the trivial case $g(0)=0$ (making $g$ everywhere continuous) would give you an $f$ with $f'=g$ everywhere